# randomizing course branching and storing data

Tags: articulate-storyline

I am a newbie to Storyline and eLearning design. I am a programmer by my previous training.

As a final project in my Instructional Design degree, I am planning to build an online course with an integrated controlled experiment on learning styles and built-in assessments.

During the experiment, learners will be randomly assigned different learning styles for the same material.

Question:
Does any tool provide flexibility to choose randomly study material, may be based on user ID?

Moreover, I want to store data after learners pass several assessments. Saved data will help to measure retention of the material studied and to evaluate the efficacy of the learning styles.

Question:
Does Storyline provide the flexibility to record data for every learner? I will probably need to capture user IDs, type of the material studied, assessment results, and maybe the time it took them to answer questions in the assessment.

I am wondering where I can read how to do the above.

Thanks.
Viktor.

Answer (score 0):

Storyline itself is just an instance of the elearning. To track user id, type of material, results, time etc you need to launch the content from an LMS, such as Moodle. https://moodle.org/

The types of data you mention are normally part of the SCORM data sent to the LMS but are not stored within Storyline itself.

You have variables which can be assigned to random values. Depending on the value, you could then jump to the specific scene with the questions in.

You can can also use a central question bank and randomise the pull of questions from that.